# What syntax should i use for member initializers?

Tags: c++, member-initialization

What  syntax should i use for member initializers in c++?

I know how to use it for Attribute but not for functions.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyClass {
    public:
        MyClass(int a, int b,int c):
            regVar(a), constVar(b),function(c)
        {}    
    public:
        int regVar;
        const int constVar;
        void function(int a){
            cout << a;
        }    
};
int main(){
    MyClass myclass(10,20);
    cout << myclass.regVar;
}
```

Thanks in advance

I tried function(c), c.function etc.

Comment: Functions can't appear in the member init list. You can call them from the constructor body if you want (in `{...}`).

Comment: Functions don't need to be initialized. They just exist as part of the object. only member variables need to be initialized. If you want to call a function, it needs to be done from the body of the constructor (also because you probably want the functions in a specific order)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat functions can appear in the member initialization list if they are used to pass parameters to base constructors, and assign values to data members, eg: `myClass() : baseClass(someFunc()), dataMember(anotherFunc()) { }`